# AngularJs If a parent element has class, hide child element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, hide

If in ng-repeat a parent div has "loaded" class i need to hide appropriate child element.

```js
<div ng-repeat="item in array" class="loading loaded">
 
  <div class="hide_it"></div>
 
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
.loaded .hide_it{
display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

CSS:

```
.loaded .hide_it {
  display: none;
}
```